# Locust integration with product SDK is not showing stats

Tags: python, python-requests, locust

I'm not getting so much in documentation for sdk load testing using Locust.

```
from locust import HttpUser, task
import random
import string
from cnvrgv2 import Cnvrg
from cnvrgv2.modules.users.users_client import UsersClient


class CnvrgUser(HttpUser):
    def on_start(self):
      print("This is on start method")
      
      # Start an instance of of the SDK
      self.cnvrg: Cnvrg = Cnvrg(domain='***',email='***',password='***', organization='performance')
      # overwrite the internal _session attribute with the locust session
      self.cnvrg._session = self.client

    @task
    def Create_project(self):
      """User creates project"""
      print("Inside project create")
      i = 0
      while i< 10:
          project_name = 'project_name' + \
        "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=6))
        
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        response = self.cnvrg.projects.create(project_name)
        i+=1
        # self.arch.assets.create(behaviours=["Builtin", "RecordEvidence", "Attachments"], attrs={"foo": "bar"})
```

As in sdk we have Session with a value `{}` as mentioned in [doc](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/testing-requests-based%20SDK%27s.html)

what is required inside this `request.Sessions`  class in my sdk

Answer (score 1):

The main requirement of this approach is that you are able to replace the SDKs internally used `requests.Session` object with Locust's `HttpSession` (`self.client`).

First of all, does your `Cnvrg` object even store its session in `_session`? (we might need to improve the docs to clarify this requirement)

If it does, can you replace it after initializing (as is done in the example in the docs), or is it too late (because your SDK has already established session cookies etc)? If so you'd need to use a more advanced approach, maybe overriding the `request` method of the  existing `Session` object.